# Bookmark plus doesn't work as expected after upgrade

Tags: bookmarks

I just updated bookmark+ package and something broke.

I use `bmkp-toggle-autonamed-bookmark-set/delete` to mark areas of interest
and return to it using:
`bmk-previous-autonamed-bookmark-repeat` /
`bmk-next-autonamed-bookmark-repeat`.

This used to be across buffers per emacs instance and it was perfect.

After the update, this does not work. I cannot use next or previous to visit
the bookmark. Even if I invoke it, it stays as if I did not press anything.
It does work within one buffer, but earlier this used to work across buffers.
Is there any new setting that needs to be made to make it work across buffers ?

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug (regression), reported by another user yesterday.

I think I've fixed it now. Please try the latest [files from Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#ObtainingBookmarkPlus) (or wait up to a day for them to be updated on MELPA).

Let me know, if you still see the problem. Thx, and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Have you considered moving your packages to source control? Emacs Wiki is a [poor platform for code distribution](https://github.com/melpa/melpa/issues/2342).